# Detect Column Hidden or Shown

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm using the `ObjectListView` control from [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net).

I'd like to detect when a user right clicks the headers and hides or shows a column.  Basically a `ColumnVisibilityChanged` event.  The reason I want to detect this is to save the visible columns between sessions.

The `ColumnWidthChanged` event fires when this occurs (not on the column that has been removed), so I *could* iterate through `AllColumns` and check the value of `IsVisible`.  However, that seems hacky and I'd like to avoid it.  Also, that would get run several times when it didn't need to.

Anyone know of a better way of detecting a column being hidden or shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a solution that wasn't quite what I was looking for, but possibly better.

`ObjectListView` has  `SaveState()` and `RestoreState()` methods as described [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-save-and-restore-the-state-of-the-objectlistview).